# Div tags inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I append JSON data to table using jQuery. I am using `jExpand plugin` to expand my rows. I want to add `class="arrow"` and `colspan="5"` to my jQuery code. It gives an error when I enter them. How can I include them in jQuery code.

```
<td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
<td colspan="5">
```

Code to append data to table

```
 $("#tableid").append("<tr><td> Product </td> <td >" + Day[0].substring(5, 11) + "</td><td> Current </td><td> Weekly </td><td> Monthly </td></tr>");

    for (var i = 1; i <= result.length; i++) {
        $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].WeeklyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].MonthlyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><div class="arrow"></div></td></tr>");
    }
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Expand table rows with jQuery - jExpand plugin - JankoAtWarpSpeed demos</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/dataBind.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            //$("#report").jExpand();
        });
    </script>        
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JankoAtWarpSpeed demos</h1>

<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >    
<table id="tableid">   
</table>
</div>
    <em>* Information taken from Wikipedia</em>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error  do you see?

Comment: String concatenation: `$("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].WeeklyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].MonthlyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><div class='arrow'></div></td></tr>");` - Since you are using `""` to enclose the string literal, either you should escape the `"` within the literal or use `'`

Comment: You should see an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in your browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny ya that was the issue. Using ' instead of " solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script should be

```
$("#tableid").append("<tr><td> Product </td> <td >" + Day[0].substring(5, 11) + "</td><td> Current </td><td> Weekly </td><td> Monthly </td></tr>");

for (var i = 1; i <= result.length; i++) {
    //here your html breaks that fixed
    $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].WeeklyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><img src='images/" + result[i].MonthlyWeather + ".png' /></td><td><div class='arrow'></div></td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget to give an explanation of what the problem is and how this helps.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Let him take his time :P He wanted to be the _first_

Comment: Their is quote problem for `class="arrow"` that should be `class='arrow'`

Comment: Also do that for `colspan="5"` to `colspan='5'` where do you want to put.

Comment: @Parth It solved the problem. Thank you all for the quick responses